# XCUIElement doubleClick function does not work

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, double-click, xcode-ui-testing, mouseup

I'm testing Cocoa app UI. I have NSTextField subclass where I override mouseUp event to catch double click (code bellow).

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseUp(with: event)

    if event.clickCount == 2 {
        Swift.print("Double click triggered")
    }
}
```

This textField added to UI. When recording UI test, double click is triggered and the following code is generated on test method.

```
XCUIApplication().windows.staticTexts["Label"].doubleClick()
```

But once I run this UI test, it does not call *mouseUp* function at all.
If I use *click* instead of *doubleClick*, *mouseUp* called as expected.

I couldn't find similar issue on the internet. Does anybody knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You do `super.mouseUp` inside `mouseDown`?

Comment: I was experimenting with both *mouseUp* and *mouseDown* and at some point forgot to change super call. I have changed that already,  Anyway, that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: i tested you code but i doesn't have any doubleclick() function. Which xcode or swift version did you used? Try it with doubleTap()

Comment: @emoleumassi are you testing mac os x or iOS app?

Comment: That's why you're seeing doubleTap instead of doubleClick. I'm testing Cocoa app (mac OS).